# Swift without stroryboard crash

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm trying to learn the new Swift language and I can't figure out a crash.

I have deleted the storyBoard cause I hate it, and this is my appDelegate code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    var vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)

    var navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    return true
}
```

but I get a crash and this is what I get:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I thought the view property isn't connected but it is...

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new project and deselect the use storyboards option